# Can i install dnf on debian?

Tags: debian, apt, dnf

to setup do a image of a fedora distribution myself.
 i would like to run the dnf package manager (fedora) on debian, as this tool allows to download and install rpm packages in an specified target dir.

Is there an repository , how can  i get "dnf installed on a debian/jessie?

something like this would be great

```
apt-get install dnf
```

rpm and python3 are already installed. so i just need "dnf"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"yum" (predecessor to dnf) exists as package on debian.

```
apt-get install yum
```

As yum is to 95% compatible with "dnf"  I could achieve what i originally wanted without "dnf", which I still would prefer, to avoid future problems.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are talking about a chroot.  I was unable to do everything using yum from the repository as in Mandragor's answer, but that was enough to get me bootstrapped.  I started by installing yum from the Ubuntu repository, as per that answer:

```
# apt install yum
```

then installing the Fedora repository package into my chroot:

```
# server=https://download.fedoraproject.org
# serverpath=pub/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/f
# serverfile=fedora-repos-28-1.noarch.rpm
# wget $server/$serverpath/$serverfile
# rpm -i --nodeps --force --root=/srv/chroot/fedora28 $serverfile
```

and then installing dnf into the chroot:

```
# yum --installroot=/srv/chroot/fedora28 --releasever=28 install -y \
    --nogpgcheck dnf
```

After that I was able to continue using dnf in the chroot:

```
# cp /etc/resolv.conf /srv/chroot/fedora28/etc
# chroot /srv/chroot/fedora28 dnf --releasever=28 install -y --nogpgcheck \
    <packages...>
```

Comment: I got `Error: Invalid version flag: if` when trying to install dnf like that.